# Is there a big performance difference if you don't use console.timeEnd()?

Tags: javascript, performance

just want to know 
especially in IE 11 edge mode 
if I used

```
console.time('log');
```

but didn't properly end it with

```
console.timeEnd('log');
```

will there be a big issue to browser's performance issues?

will the timer keeps on calculating and causing memory leak if not ended.

if there are hundreds of console.time() started but never properly ended in spa application page.. senarios like these

in another word, if this method is pretty safe even when forget to write timeEnd in performance tuning test.

Comment: Doubt it.......

Comment: The minimal difference will be vastly overshadowed by the parsing of the full script. So no, not really.

Comment: Why downvote? Can anyone explain?

Comment: FWIW: The "timer" is effectively just a starting time associated with a name: ie. and improved form of `myStartTimes["foo"] = Date.now()`. *There is no active "running" component*; only some collected data that is hanging around indefinitely. Does this collection of data 'take up memory'? Yes (of inconsequential sizes for realistic calls; MDN lists 10k as a MAXIMUM number allowed). Does it seem like slopping debugging-left-in-code? Yes. Does it cause a run-time impact? No as, again, there is no active component.

Comment: You can always measure it yourself with the [performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure) builtin, which is relatively simple.

Comment: reasonable, same as timestamp.